# Как обновить adb.exe для Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

Запускаю эмулятор в Android Studio, появляется окно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что с этим делать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Обновите sdk platform tools. Tools-> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools вкладка.

Comment: @Андроид Андроид, подскажите, пожалуйста, как его обновить, я пока что не нашёл (я отредактировал вопрос, чтоб была видна его версия)

Comment: Проверьте в файле проекта `local.properties` или в меню "Project structure" совпадает ли указанный там путь к SDK с тем, что на втором скрине. Если да, то попробуйте создать через AVD-manager новое виртуальное устройство и запустить на нём.

Answer (score 0):

Настройки Android Studio, System Setting, updates

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

Я обновился так: Скачал ADB RUN и перекинул три файла adb.exe, AdbWinApi.dll, AdbWinUsbApi.dll отсюда C:\adb_run\bin в папку C:\Windows с заменой файлов